# Back button in ActionBar gets hidden in the ListView activity started by Fragments in Tabs

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-actionbar, back-button

I have 3 nested activity. The first one contains 3 fragments within each is a button which starts a second activity. In the second activity I have a ListView. When the user clicks on an item in ListView the third activity is started.

My problem is that in second activities there is no back button in action bar.

Is the problem caused by Activity being started from within a fragment?
I have no clue on what is causing this problem.

My first activity is an ActionBarActivity and I use FragmentPagerAdapter.

Please tell me which parts of the code of manifest I should put here to be considered. 
Thanks in advance.

(please note that I'm not willing to programmatically solve this. I need to know what is causing the problem)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the **up** button in the *ActionBar* you need to set your activities to have a parent activity like so:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:label="@string/second_activity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="MainActivity" />
    ...
</activity
```

Please show your Manifest file if it doesn't work this way.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I did not know and was looking for. One more q though. Is there any problem that two activity have the same "android:name" value?

Comment: It's possible but why would you want it?

Comment: I don't want it. It just happened cause of my lack of knowledge for manifest. I copies you code in mine and there was already one name exactly like that. And I did not know what other name could I use. That's all. If I can use any other name I will.

Comment: android:name specifies the activity for which the settings that follow will be applied to. You should add `android:parentActivityName=".YourParentActivity"` and the `<meta-data.. />` to the activity that you want to have *up* button.

Comment: I meant the android:name in meta-data. not the android:parentActivityName. The former seems to be of no use. What does it do really?

Comment: android:parentActivityName is for API 16+, while <meta-data is meant to support API 7+. It's all in the [<Android API guide>](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home). A good read :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you have added

```
setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean);
```

in onCreate() of your activity?